# How to solve a boundary value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

for this question I'm having trouble with finding a particular equation, and solving this equation. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Solve $y'' + \pi^2y = 6x, 0<x<1$

$y(0)+y'(0) = 0, y(1) = 0$

$m^2 + \pi^2 = 0$

$ m = +- i\pi$

$y_c = c_1cos\pi x+ c_2sin\pi x$

Comment: Great, that's the homogeneous solution. Now you need a particular solution so you can solve for the coefficients. Do you know how to find particular solutions for problems like this? There are a few standard methods...

Comment: How do we find a particular solution for this type of question if there's bounds on the x?

Comment: Ignore the bounds, just find a particular solution to the equation that holds everywhere, and it will hold on the particular interval as well.

Comment: So what would the particular solution be? I think that's where I'm having trouble, like I can find ones from 6X+1 for example or just 6, but I can't find one for 6x

Comment: If you can find a solution for a right side of $6x+1$, say $f$, and a solution for a right side of $6$, say $g$, then $f-g/6$ will solve this problem (why?). This is definitely not the most efficient way to solve this particular problem, but it will work.

Comment: I'm very confused. What would a particular solution for 6x look like?

Comment: Nvm I think I figured it out